# Unpermitted parameters in rails 4. Parameters passed are being rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a scenario where I have events and events has_many speakers. When I pass speaker_ids as parameters it is showing as unpermitted parameters speaker_ids. My controller

```
params.require(:events).permit(:id, :description, :speaker_ids => [])
```

have added `accepts_nested_attributes_for speakers, :allow_destroy => true`

but it still throws unpermitted parameters on the console and I'm unable to update the events details with speakers information.

Comment: Look at the parameters being passed in for `:speaker_ids`. Each of the parameters needs to be whitelisted. If you're passing in deleted records, that probably includes the magic `deleted` parameter, though I can't remember exactly what format that comes in.